# change content of recyclerview based on user input android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[image]

I need help in finding a way to change the content of a RecyclerView based on a user choice. I am making an android app that displays news from abc news as default but I want to give the user the choice to pick another source such as cnn etc. I have this options in a spinner and have called the `onItemSelected()` where I can get which source the user picked. With the new source I call the loadNews(Source) method which makes the request to the news api and gets the data. I will post my code hope someone can help.As of right now when I open the news activity it loads the news from abc but when I pick another source it does not reload the data from the different source, it stays with the same content!

**Code for Activity**

```
private String Source ="abc-news";
private Spinner spinner;

private List<Article> articles;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);

    // getting the news service
    newsService = Common.getNewsService();
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    kbv = findViewById(R.id.kbv);
    swipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh);
    spinner  =(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.drop_Down_News_Source);

    loadSpinner();


    // originally load from abc news and if user wants to change they can select from the list and reload the news
    // initialize the recycler
    loadNews(this.Source);


    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new   SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            loadNews(Source);
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            },4000);

        }
    });


}

private void loadSpinner() {

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> myAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.News_Sources, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);

}


public void loadNews(String Source){
    newsService.getArticles(Common.getAPIUrl(Source)).enqueue(new Callback<News>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<News> call, Response<News> response) {
            Picasso.get()
                    .load(response.body().getArticles().get(0).getUrlToImage())
                    .into(kbv);

            articles = response.body().getArticles();

            articles.remove(0);
            RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(newsActivity.this, articles, newsActivity.this);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(newsActivity.this));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<News> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(newsActivity.this,"Something went wrong!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onClickListener(View view, int position) {
if(articles != null && view != null){
    Intent intent = new Intent(newsActivity.this, webviewClass.class);
    intent.putExtra("article_url", articles.get(position).getUrl());
    startActivity(intent);
}
else{
    Toast.makeText(this, "something went wrong in clickListener  method!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
  switch (position){
      case 0 :
          Source = "cbs-news";
          break;
      case 1 :
          Source = "espn";
          break;
      case 2:
          Source ="cnn";
          break;
      case 3:
          Source = "mtv-news";
          break;
      case 4:
          Source = "nbc-news";
          break;
          default:
              Source ="abc-news";
  }
  loadNews(Source);
}
```

Comment: Instead of calling the loadNews(Source) try calling loadSpinner() and inside that call loadNews(Source)

Comment: That big answer? That was just a copy of https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview, so if that was helpful, now you have the link. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't set listener for your spinner.

`spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);`

Answer (score 0):

Your spinner does not have a listener to listen to changes in values. Add this piece of code after setting the adapter to your spinner.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Furthermore, your activity will now implement the spinner's itemSelected listener as well.

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: this is such an embarrassment such a careless mistake haha!